# Does Roslyn support code fix actions for project/compilation-level diagnostics (with no location)?

Tags: roslyn, roslyn-code-analysis

Let's report some diagnostic and register code fix for this diagnostic.

```
private static void OnCompilation(CompilationAnalysisContext context) {
    var compilation = context.Compilation;
    var diagnostic = Diagnostic.Create( Rule, (Location) null );
    context.ReportDiagnostic( diagnostic );
}

public sealed override Task RegisterCodeFixesAsync(CodeFixContext context) {
    var document = context.Document;
    //var span = context.Span;
    var diagnostic = context.Diagnostics.Single();
    RegisterCodeFix( context, $"Fix compilation", diagnostic, Action );

    Task<Solution> Action(CancellationToken cancellationToken) {
        return Task.FromResult( document.Project.Solution );
    }
}
```

Problem is that: **there is no way to execute code fix action.** Light bulb is not shown.
And even if I could execute it then document were null here.

So, is it possible to make code fix for compilation-level diagnostics?

Comment: Does it work on your unit tests?

Comment: `CodeFixContext` throws `ArgumentNullException` when document is null. So, tests doesn't work. But I don't use roslyn testing library. Maybe there this problem is somehow solved.

Answer (score 0):

Code fixes for project-level diagnostics are not supported.
https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/discussions/50087#discussioncomment-230367